# Как правильно: в лице, на лице или по лицу?

Tags: выбор-слов

***В лице (по лицу или на лице)*** читалось разочарование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***На лице (его) читалось разочарование.***

Пояснение

1)Практически во всех текстах встречаются такие выражения: ***читалось на лице***, но ***читалось в глазах, во взгляде, в движениях*** и т.д.

**На их лицах ясно читалось** смущение от того, что им пришлось раздеться, но они прятали его под показной бравадой, преувеличенно жестикулируя и хохоча. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

Но вот волна коснулась колен вождя, и он остановился. **На лице его читалось** смятение.  [Николай Митрофанов. Уголок ада в Океании // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

Видин вскинул голову. **В глазах его читалось** изумление. ― При чем здесь совесть? [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но… (2011)]

Кая смотрела на него широко открытыми **глазами, в которых читалос**ь такое… такое… [Виктор Пелевин. S.N.U.F.F (2011)]

2) Глагол ***прочитать*** сочетается с предложной формой Д.п.:

Ольховцева пристально посмотрела на Михалкина, пытаясь ***прочитать по лицу,*** поверил ли он или нет. [Александр Савельев. Аркан для букмекера (2000)]

3) Как  объяснить выбор предлога? Здесь учитывается пространственное значение предлогов НА и В: ***на чём*** ― на поверхности предмета, в чём ― внутри предмета, имеющего объем.